# Wrong characters when installing 海通大智慧

Tags: windows-7, character-encoding, chinese

I installed [海通大智慧](http://download.htsec.com/ChannelHome/4051009/index.shtml) on Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate (English version). However, the characters are clearly wrong (it is supposed to be in Chinese, but the characters mix up Chinese and Korean characters. Everywhere. And their concatenation makes no sense, i.e. a mojibake. It's like saying sdfgghngewrfdg):

[image]

What could be the issue?

Comment: Helps if you point out what exactly is wrong with the screenshot.  Dialog box buttons being in English while he message isn't, isn't obvious enough, since that isn't all that strange

Comment: Ramhound beat me to it.  It isn't clear what the issue is.  I don't know Chinese, but there are Chinese-looking characters in the title and question, and all of the screen content other than the digits and the button text.  What I assume is the end result picture in your answer looks the same as the picture in the question.  What are we looking for?  BTW, I didn't downvote, but that would be a logical explanation for the votes.

Comment: the characters mix up Chinese and Korean characters. Everywhere. And their concatenation makes no sense. It's like saying sdfgghngewrfdg.

Comment: That's going to be totally lost on this audience.  SU is an English-only site, so very few readers will recognize the difference.  Definitely add that explanation to the question.

Comment: @fixer1234 added, is it ok?

Comment: Better.  Your Q&A would probably get a better reception if your issue had involved a European language and an Asian language, so the problem was more obvious to the bulk of SU's readers.  :-)

Comment: I reversed my vote, only because the question now indicates what is wrong, and its a self-answer.  The real problem once the clarification was provided, explains the original screenshot in more detail, everything that isn't being handled by the program itself is simply gibberish due current language setting simply not containing the correct characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It requires to change the language for non-unicode programs to Chinese:

[image]

[image]

[image]